# What difference between symfony's testing and browser

Tags: php, symfony, testing

I encounter a problem about symfony's testing.
Here is my action source code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $yac = new \Yac();
    return new JsonResponse($yac->info());
}
```

And this is my testing source code:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('GET', 'http://admin.bac.com/');
    var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

Position A get false, when using `phpunit` to test. The screenshot is below:
[image]

But it's normal when using browser. The result:

```
{
    "memory_size": 71303168, 
    "slots_memory_size": 4194304, 
    "values_memory_size": 67108864, 
    "segment_size": 4194304, 
    "segment_num": 16, 
    "miss": 0, 
    "hits": 0, 
    "fails": 0, 
    "kicks": 0, 
    "recycles": 0, 
    "slots_size": 32768, 
    "slots_used": 0
}
```

**So, I don't know what difference between symfony's testing and browser.**
Or, this is the problem of **Yac** extension?

Comment: perhaps your function createClient don't return a valid connexion...

Comment: what is a valid connection?  The $yac object is created, but there's any property and method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the YAC [source code](https://github.com/laruence/yac/blob/master/yac.c#L718-L746) of the `info()` function, you get `false` because YAC is not enabled in the CLI environment.

So just add `yac.enable=1` in `php.ini` of the CLI environment.

Comment: Yes,  Thanks very much !